Group of rotations of the cube
I am trying to, for self-study, prove that the group $G$ of rotations of a cube is isomorphic to the symmetric group $S_4$. There are other questions on this, but I am trying to work through the details on my own without consulting previous attempts. I used this visual tool from Geogebra to inform the geometry of my answer.

Every rotation of the cube corresponds to a permutation of the four body diagonals joining opposite vertices. By mapping each element of $G$ to the permutation it induces on the diagonals, we get a homomorphism $f: G \to S_4$. By considering the rotation through the axis joining the midpoints of two opposite sides of the cube, we find that $\text{Im}(f)$ contains each of the $6$ transpositions in $S_4$. These transpositions generate $S_4$, so $f(G) \supset S_4$. That is, $f$ is surjective. The order of $G$ is $24$, however. The cube has six faces, any of which can be facing upward, and given a fixed such square face, there are $4$ possible rotations of this square that preserve the cube. So $|G| = 6 \times 4 = 24$. As $|G| = |S_4|$ and $f$ is surjective, it is bijective. So $G \cong S_4$.

Is my reasoning here sound? I have been struggling with this question for some time, so I would appreciate any clarifications on the steps of the argument for which my reasoning may be fuzzy.

The "related" question list includes The group of rigid motions of the cube is isomorphic to $S_4$. and Find the rotation symmetries of cube in terms of the four long diagonals. These might be of interest, although I think this question is quite distinct from either of those others due to the specific proof proposed here.

Yes, your proof is correct.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.
